# create dynamic linked variables

Tags: python, variables, dynamic

Is it possible to create a dynamic linked variable? So that changes in `original_VAR` will automatically take effect in `copied_VAR` ? Like so:

```
original_VAR = 'original_VAL'
copied_VAR = original_VAR

original_VAR = 'modified_VAL'

print(copied_VAR)
#desired output:
>>>> 'modified_VAL'
```

A similar behavior can be created for lists under few conditions:

```
original_DICT_ARR = [{'key': 'original_VAL'}]


# 1 - does not create a dynamic link
copied_DICT_ARR = [value for value in original_DICT_ARR]

# 2 - does create a dynamic link
copied_DICT_ARR = original_DICT_ARR

# 3 - does create a dynamic link, if the copied element is a list or dict, but not if string, boolean, int, float
copied_DICT_ARR = []
copied_DICT_ARR.append(original_DICT_ARR[0])

# MODIFICATION:
original_DICT_ARR[0]['key'] = 'modified_VAL'

# RESULT for 2,3
print(copied_DICT_ARR[0])

>>>> {'key': 'modified_VAL'}
```

**Why would I want to do this?**

I am building a list, the list is full of dict objects. I need to assign a value to a certain dict key.

Later, that value might change - I don't want to loop through all dictionaries in the list again. I want to change the original variable, and have the effect taken place in all dictionaries automatically.

Comment: No, there is no way to do this. You can, of course, reference the same *object* with different variables, and then *mutate* that object, and those changes will be reflected, but you cannot link two variables, where re-assigning a variable automatically re-assigns the other

Comment: You are misunderstanding your examples, there are no "dynamic links". In some cases, you are merely referencing **the same object**, e.g. `copied_DICT_ARR = original_DICT_ARR`. That **does not make a copy**. When you mutate that object, of course, any reference to that object will see that mutation. `int`,  `str`, `bool`, `float`, `tuple` objects are immutable, they don't expose mutator methods. You really need to read: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: The simple solution is to fill your dictionaries with some mutable object. Simply, `class Value: def __init__(self, value): self.value = value`, Then, `value = Value(0)`, create  your list of dicts with `value`, then you can do  `value.value = 99`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep a reference the specific `dict` you want to modify later. Since it refers to the same underlying dict - changes will be reflected in your reference. Like so:

```
original_DICT_ARR = [{'key': 'original_VAL'}, {'key': 'another_val'}]

target_dict = original_DICT_ARR[0]

# MODIFICATION:
original_DICT_ARR[0]['key'] = 'modified_VAL'

# RESULT for 2,3
print(target_dict)
```

Gives:

```
{'key': 'modified_VAL'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this and keep things abstract by using a mutable object and subclassing [UserDict](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.UserDict) and overriding `__getitem__`:

```
class ChangingVal:
def __init__(self, val):
    self.val = val

class ChangingValsDict(UserDict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        ret = self.data[key]
        if isinstance(ret, ChangingVal):
            ret = ret.val
        return ret

my_dict = ChangingValsDict()

changing_val = ChangingVal(3) 
my_dict["changing_value"] = changing_val

print(my_dict["changing_value"]) # -- outputs "3"

# change your value
changing_val.val = 6

print(my_dict["changing_value"]) # -- outputs "6"
```